# Authorizing a user logged in via ArcGIS Online/Javascript in a Python server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

So, let's say I have this application built via WebAppBuilder, the user is already logged in via a ArcgisOnline organization, but I have a separate python server that does some custom geoprocessing and need to be authorized.

Questions :

1) How do I retrieved an already logged in user information? I won't have access to his password but probably can get a token or something (Javascript API 3.X Preferably).

2) How do I authorize the information retrieved above in a python script?

Pseudo example (Python server code):

```
def authenticate(request):
  token = request.token #Or whatever other information is necessary
  valid = arcpy.isAuthenticated(token) #Just a pseudo example
  if valid:
    return Response.ok()
  return Response.fail()
```

Comment: Your question is based on the premise that the token generated in the Javascript application will be usable in Python. I think you need to manually verify that you can hijack and reuse a token in that way. Further, you wont use the token to "authorize" inside the Python script. The token (if it works) is already 'authorized'. You'd append it to a request that is made, most likely through HTTP libraries like `Requests` or `URLLIB`

Comment: @KHibma I won't actually be making any requests to ArcGIS Rest API in Python, I only want to know if the user from Javascript has a valid token

Comment: If that's the case, why are you going to the trouble of calling into an independent service (like a geoprocessing service running python)? Why don't you just try to check the `expires` of a token in JS and if necessary `refreshToken()`: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/credential-amd.html

Comment: @KHibma because the point is not to validate the token, but add authentication to the python service so that it's not public. I'm trying to do it in a way that won't require an extra login